# Access zeroth index of a JSON array in Android

Tags: android

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{"response": 
{"legislators": 
    [
        {"legislator": 
            {
                               "fax": "", "name": "John Doe"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

There is only 1 element under the legislator array. I've tried to access it using the zeroth index, but I've not been able to. I get an "org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)". What am I doing wrong?

```
                        JSONObject response = jsonObject
                            .getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray legislators = response
                            .getJSONArray("legislators");
                    JSONObject first = legislators..getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("legislator");

                    Log.i("Kuscco", "" + first.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to treat the string response as a big JSON object before you retrieve the JSONObject "response". Then you can proceed with getting the JSONArray and the first object inside it.

Try this code to start with:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"response\": {\"legislators\": [ {\"legislator\": {\"fax\": \"\", \"name\": \"John Doe\"}}]}}";
JSONObject object;
try {
    object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONObject response = object.getJSONObject("response");
    JSONArray legislators = response.getJSONArray("legislators");
    JSONObject first = legislators.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("legislator");
    Log.d("Kuscco STACK ++++++ ", "" + first.getString("name"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```